# Find and replace object property value using underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Suppose that I have an json as follow.How could i replace the json `status` to `inactive` based on the key `status`.

Keyword: replace, underscore

```
{
    "id": "0001",
    "name": "Test",
    "status": "active"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`_.each()`](http://underscorejs.org/#each) for this

```
_.each(YourArray, function(p){
    if(p.status === "active") p.status = "inactive";
    // or
    p.status = p.status === "active" ? "inactive" : p.status;
});
```

But why You want use [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) for this task? You can resolve it with "vanilla" js:

```
for(var i = 0,  l = YourArray.length; i < l; i++){
    if(YourArray[i].status === "active") YourArray[i].status = "inactive";
}
```

Or use [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
YourArray.forEach(function(p){
    if(p.status === "active") p.status = "inactive";
});
```